# Selenium Java :- [1553593587.996][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000 [1553593587.997][WARNING]: screenshot failed, retrying

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, chromedriver, timeout

I am using Selenium 3.14.0 with Java to automate my tests. Until yesterday(25Mar 2018) , everything was up and running fine.In case of any failures , screenshots were taken and embedded successfully. This morning however the script started crashing with following error.

> [1553593587.996][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
>   [1553593587.997][WARNING]: screenshot failed, retrying
>   [1553593597.997][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
>   [1553593608.000][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
>   [1553593608.000][WARNING]: screenshot failed, retrying
>   [1553593618.000][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
>   [1553593628.004][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
>   [1553593628.004][WARNING]: screenshot failed, retrying
>   [1553593638.004][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
>   timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000

I am using

> headless chrome=73.0.3683.86 and chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
>
> Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e3..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Jenkins\AppData\Lo...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:3956}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: none, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: ignore, unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore, version: 73.0.3683.86, webStorageEnabled: true}
>   Session ID: 95fc01b26bcafb4607a4760ef58a8930
>   Starting ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72)

In order to resolve this , I tried adding varios paramters to options such as :-

> options.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation" );
>           options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);

but none of it resolved timeout issue.

I really appreciate an advise on how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Is this reproducible in different environments, but some browser configuration>

Comment: I am running it only on one environment which is the jenkins server. but when I run it locally on Windows 10 Chrome brower then I dont see this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are using **chromedriver=73.0.3683.68** and **chrome=73.0.3683.86** on **Windows OS**

John Chen (Owner - chromedriver) recently have confirmed that:

> We have confirmed issues with take screenshot when Chrome 73.0.3686.75 is started by a service (such as Jenkins or Task scheduler) on Windows. Please see https://crbug.com/942023 for more details. We apologize for any inconvenience caused by this.
>
> However, we haven't yet been able to observe similar issue on Linux, so we appreciate any help you can provide to enable us to reproduce the issue on Linux. We don't have access to TeamCity, but we have tested take screenshot using Docker image produced by Selenium (selenium/standalone-chrome:3.141.59-lithium), and didn't find any problems.

[image: chromedriver73]

---

### Update

We were able to dig up the main issue. The main issue is not with *ChromeDriver v73.x* as such but with **Chrome v73.x** and John officially confirms it as:

> The root cause is indeed in Chrome 73.x, not in ChromeDriver. We are working with Chrome devs to find a solution.

[image: chrome73_issue]

---

### Solution

The solution would be to:

- Downgrade *Chrome Browser* to **Chrome v72.x**
- Use a matching *ChromeDriver* among:

  - [ChromeDriver 2.46](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.46/)
  - [ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=72.0.3626.69/)

> Note: If you are using Chrome version 72, please download ChromeDriver 2.46 or ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69

---

### Outro

- Discussion: [Page.captureScreenshot no longer works in Chrome 73 under Selenium as a Service on Windows](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=942023)
- Commit causing the issue: [Set VizDisplayCompositor feature enabled on desktop platforms](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/73a59e05c556d9bf3f9ac16dfc5f11862f08ab4b)
- Merge: 
  [latency: Remove snapshots from LatencyInfo](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/1095562)
- [Download Google Chrome 72 Offline Installer For All Operating Systems](https://www.itechtics.com/download-google-chrome-72-offline-installer-for-all-operating-systems/)

---

### Update(04-April-2019)

Adding the argument `--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor` through an instance of `ChromeOptions()` seems solves the issue:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://google.com");
```

Comment: Sir, I am using version 75 for both `chrome` and `chromebinary` and using following `chrome options` in `serenity.properties` file  lie this `chrome.switches="--test-type,disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor,acceptInsecureCerts=true,--disable-web-security,--ignore-certificate-errors,--allow-running-insecure-content,--allow-insecure-localhost,--whitelisted-ips='',--disable-infobars,--disable-gpu,--verbose"`, but it is still giving this error. Please give your suggestion.I'll really appreciate, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
options.addArguments("disable-gpu");
```

Previously raised in:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959986/how-to-solve-selenium-chromedriver-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-exc

Comment: Used all the following options but still have the same issue :- options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        options.addArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
        options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation" );
        options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);

Comment: In that case take a look at https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9007/how-to-handle-time-out-receiving-message-from-the-renderer-in-chrome-driver. Main points are that it can be caused by version mismatch between Chrome and Chromedriver or by timeouts rendering the page (usually by 3rd party plugins). So increase / disable driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(timeoutValue, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Answer (score 0):

Using combination of following options resolved my timeout issue :-

> options.addArguments("--incognito");
>      options.addArguments("enable-automation");
>           options.addArguments("--headless");
>           options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
>           options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
>           options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
>           options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
>           options.addArguments("--dns-prefetch-disable");
>   options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL);

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on the same date and the problem was caused by a bug in the lastest version of chrome that only manifests when the chrome instance is opened from a service (such as a build server like Team City).

I resolved the issue by downgrading to an older version of chrome, but if this can be fixed with arguments, this is a better solution.

See here for more information:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=848

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364056/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-10-000-while-capturing-screenshot-usi/55379488#55379488